# Can't format sd card

Tags: gparted, delete, sd-card, disk-formatting

Yesterday I found an old micro SD card laying in my drawer and decided to check what's in it using an adapter. The card contained some non-important files and I deleted them.

I took it out and put it back in to check if everything's OK, but I saw that the files are still there. I repeated the process, yet still the files remain.

I tried formatting it few times, but an error always pops out:

```
udisks-error-quark 0
```

I also tried using GParted and failed.

I tried formatting it one last time and this time an error didn't even pop up. How can I format the card?

Comment: Sounds like the SD card is bad.  I have plenty of those that will not format nor can I delete anything from them but I can read them almost fine.

Comment: If possible, can you try the card on another computer?

Answer (score 1):

SD cards have a habit of dying, even when you buy good brands: The amount of write cycles is limited. I found MicroSD even worse, in particular when using them in a smartphone; smartphones tend to write a lot on those cards. After a year or two of normal use, they tend to be toast.

My advice is: Trash that thing and get a new one. Those made for security cameras are somewhat more expensive, but they seem to be made for more write cycles.

Comment: Yes, I second that. Tried several time to resurrect a sdcard. It might even work - until you write something on it. To avoid hassle just put it in the trash bin.

Answer (score 0):

Try

Delete partition using gparted.

Create new partion table.

Create new partion

Then format and let us know!

It might work. with new partion.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and It was solved when I formatted the sd card using my Samsung galaxy s9 plus phone using the phone storage settings